# Relax function on Bellman Ford Algorithms

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, recursive-algorithms, trees

In a Weighted Directed Graph $G$ (with positive weights), with $n$ vertex and $m$ edges, we want to calculate the shortest path from vertex $1$ to other vertexes. we use $1$-dimensional array $D = (d_1,\cdots,d_n)$, and $D_1=0$ and others filled with $+\infty$. for updating the array we **just** premit to use the $\mathrm{Relax}(u, v)$ function,

1. **if** $(\, D[v] > D[u] + W(u, v) \,)$ **then**
2. $\quad D(v) \leftarrow D(u)+W(u,v)$
3. **endif**

In which $W(u, v)$ is the weight of $u \implies v$ edge. How many time (at least) we must call the Relax function to ensure that for each vertex $u$, $D[u]$ be equals to length of shortest path from vertex $1$ to $u$.

Solution:

> My TA says this is just Bellman-Ford and $m \times n$ times we must call, but maybe i think we can use Dijkstra and need $m$ times.

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing you are allowed to do is use the Relax function, then indeed you're basically running Bellman-Ford. Your intuition about using Dijkstra is right in the sense that, since all weights are positive, you could apply that algorithm, but then you need to keep track of the vertex that has the current shortest distance from vertex 1. If you're not allowed to do that, then your TA is right.

So there are two solutions, in the first one you call relax $m \times n$ times:

> `for _ in 1 .. n:
>     for i in 1 ... n:
>       for every edge (i, j):
>         Relax(i, j)`

This code is basically Bellman-Ford, without a posterior check for a negative cycle. This check can be omitted since all weights are positive.

Another solution calls relax $m$ times, but searches for the vertex with the shortest distance at each step:

> `function MinDistance( S, D ):
>     min = None
>     for i in S:
>       if min is None or D[i] < min:
>         min = D[i]
>         argmin = i
>     return argmin`
>
> **function** InefficientDijkstra():
>     S = set()
>     D[1] = 0
>     S.add(1)
>     **while** **not** S.empty():
>       argmin = MinDistance( S, D )
>       **for** every edge (argmin, j):
>         old_dist = D[j]
>         Relax(argmin, j)
>         **if** D[j] < old_dist:
>           S.add(j)
>       S.remove(argmin)

This is a very inefficient way to implement Dijkstra, but it calls the Relax function only $m$ times.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm exploits the fact that the _shortest distance_ to some vertex can not become shorter, since all edge weights are positive. This allows Dijkstra's algorithm to run faster than Bellman-Ford, but restricts the algorithm to positive-weight graphs.

If you were to apply Dijkstra, you would need to:
0) Make all vertices as unmarked
1) look up the unmarked vertex with the shortest distance by going through D[u].
2) Call relax on the outgoing edges of u.
3) Mark u.
4) Go to 1 while there are unmarked vertices.

Comment: This means you indeed call relax only $m$ times, but scanning through $D$ to find the vertex with the shortest distance would be linear (unless you use a smarter choice for the data structure), so timewise you're not much faster than Bellman-Ford.

Comment: I've added some pseudocode, hope it's clear

Comment: For Dijkstra you need to find the vertex that is not yet visited and has the current shortest distance, at each step. That's the function you need, I've called it "MinDistance" in the pseudocode.

Comment: Dijkstra "visits" every vertex exactly once. When visiting a vertex, each of its outgoing edges is relaxed. Thus, relax is called for each edge in the graph. That is, $m$ times.